# How should I improve query performance while keeping the existing structure?

Tags: oracle

I want to improve the performance of the query as below. There is an index in the `isl_ref` and `isl_date` fields. But since I use the ">" or  "<" operator and I use "+", index cannot be used. That's why query performance is very low. `(1/1440)` adds a minute to the `isl_date` field. When I use the following edited query, the query performance increases and accelerates, but is this a correct structure as a Original SQL Query's structure?

**Original SQL Query:**

```
   select name from persons
    where drm in ('G','B')
    and (isl_ref = 'QR' and sysdate > isl_date + (1 /1440) )
```

**Edited SQL Query:**

```
   select name from persons
    where drm in ('G','B')
    and (isl_ref = 'QR' and (isl_date between sysdate -1 and sysdate - (1 /1440) ))
```

Comment: (1) The edited query is different from the original query.  (2) I suggested an alternative query on your earlier question.  Did you use tthat?

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but the performance did not change, this script can be taken in the date range, it can be used that way. I tried edited query for this, its performance got faster, but is this true?

Comment: can you show the explain plan for both ?

Comment: _"There is an index in the `isl_ref` and `isl_date` fields"_ -- Ambiguous. Show the _actual_ index definitions.

Comment: You created two user names, so that people can't easily cross-reference your duplicated questions? **BRILLIANT!**